# Use managed identities for Microsoft Sentinel with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to reach Sentinel APIs using the Microsoft Azure Python SDK for Sentinel (`azure-mgmt-securityinsight`) in Azure Functions and for now (locally), I'm using Credentials with the AZ CLI.

I haven't found any documentation so far, but I'm curious on whether it is possible to use Managed Identities for Sentinel with Azure Functions?

Any experience with that or documentation?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found any documentation so far, but I'm curious on whether it is possible to use Managed Identities for Sentinel with Azure Functions?

Here is the suitable [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/connect-azure-functions-template?tabs=MPY) for connecting Sentinel to the data source by using Azure Functions.

It is mentioned that various languages are supported for the above scenario including Python SDK that allows the Sentinel in the data source's REST API.

Also, there are some permissions should be granted on the RBAC Level on both Sentinel Workspace and Azure Functions, given in the same document.

And it is given in this GitHub Issue #[4227](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/issues/4227), only System-Assigned Managed Identity is supported for Azure Sentinel Playbooks but not the User-assigned Managed Identity and if it is the Azure Sentinel Logic Apps Connector Managed Identity Context, then refer to this MS Tech Community [Article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/what-s-new-managed-identity-for-azure-sentinel-logic-apps/ba-p/2068204).

Comment: I've seen that documentation previously and it doesn't answer my question. I'm not ingesting any data into Sentinel, I'm querying for Sentinel resources like Analytic rules. I'm looking for something similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/configure-managed-identities-cluster?tabs=portal).

Comment: The link you provided is identities on the Data Explorer Cluster but not the identities on Azure Sentinel right

Comment: Yes yes, I'm fully aware it's about ADX. I'm just interested in knowing how to enable a similar property in Sentinel.

Comment: I have given the links that gives information about managed identities on both the Sentinel Playbooks and Sentinel Logic Apps Connector. Could you check and let me know if any info required.